# How to loop through a blob upload in Azure Swift?

Tags: swift, azure, azure-blob-storage

I want to upload to a blob in azure swift but I don't know when the upload is completed to go to a segue here is the code

```
//Save the image to the azurecloud
    do {
        let account = try AZSCloudStorageAccount(fromConnectionString:azureAccessKey) //I stored the property in my header file
        let blobClient: AZSCloudBlobClient = account.getBlobClient()
        let blobContainer: AZSCloudBlobContainer = blobClient.containerReference(fromName: containerName)

        let imageName =  "SampleList"

        let blob: AZSCloudBlockBlob = blobContainer.blockBlobReference(fromName: imageName)


        for (index, item) in uploadedImages.enumerated() {
            let productNameFixed = productNameTextField.text!.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "_", options: .literal, range: nil)
            let imageSubName = String(userId) + "_" + productNameFixed
            let imageName =  imageSubName + "_" + String(index)

            let blob: AZSCloudBlockBlob = blobContainer.blockBlobReference(fromName: imageName)
            let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(item)



            blob.upload(from: imageData!, completionHandler: {(NSError) -> Void in
                NSLog("Uploaded" + imageName)
                print("We have uploaded the image")

                self.checkBoxForMovingOn.append(index)

            })
        }





        print("done uploading")
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "productPostSuccessful", sender:  self)
```

I want to basically know when my list of images is done uploading so I can segue to a new controller to display those images. What is happening is that I segue to the controller without finishing the image upload and I get errors.

Comment: Do you know the number of images you want to download ?

Comment: Have you gotten a chance to read through the proposed answer Jov ?

Comment: Yes Mr. Adam I managed to fix the answer myself and your answer is pretty much the same. I want to accept your answer but it's not letting me currently? I would like some more help if you have time.

Comment: it should let you accept to mark it as an answer. 
sure what kind of issues are you still experiencing? feel free to add it here, or open a new question if it requires a lot of details.

Comment: It has something to do with a storyboard and how to clone certain controllers. Is it possible to tag you in my new question? Thank you adam..

Comment: I don't think you could tag me, but I do check the forums on a daily basis, if you put it in, i'd check it either today or tomorrow, in addition other people from the StackOverflow community may help as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you happen to know the number of images you want to upload ?

I'm not familiar with swift, but will provide a logical answer for this scenario, you could use two situations:

I'd recommend checking File stack, it has an example in swift on using Azure Blob upload, and tracking the progress in swift:

```
// Initialize a `Policy` with the expiry time and permissions you need.
let oneDayInSeconds: TimeInterval = 60 * 60 * 24 // expires tomorrow
let policy = Policy(// Set your expiry time (24 hours in our case)
                    expiry: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: oneDayInSeconds),
                    // Set the permissions you want your policy to have
                    call: [.pick, .read, .store])

// Initialize a `Security` object by providing a `Policy` object and your app secret.
// You can find and/or enable your app secret in the Developer Portal.
guard let security = try? Security(policy: policy, appSecret: "YOUR-APP-SECRET") else {
    return
}

// Get an URL pointing to the local file you would like to upload.
guard let localURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "YOUR-IMAGE", withExtension: "jpg") else {
    return
}

// Initialize your `Client` object by passing a valid API key, and security options.
let client = Client(apiKey: "YOUR-API-KEY", security: security)

let uploadProgress: (Progress) -> Void = { progress in
    // Here you may update the UI to reflect the upload progress.
    print("Progress: \(progress)")
}

// Store options
let storeOptions: StorageOptions = StorageOptions(// Store location (e.g. S3, Dropbox, Rackspace, Azure, Google Cloud Storage)
                                                  location: .s3,
                                                  // AWS Region for S3 (e.g. "us-east-1", "eu-west-1", "ap-northeast-1", etc.)
                                                  region: "us-east-1",
                                                  // The name of your S3 bucket
                                                  container: "YOUR-S3-BUCKET",
                                                  // Destination path in the store.
                                                  // You may use a path to a folder (e.g. /public/) or,
                                                  // alternatively a path containing a filename (e.g. /public/oncorhynchus.jpg).
                                                  // When using a path to a folder, the uploaded file will be stored at that folder using a
                                                  // filename derived from the original filename.
                                                  // When using a path to a filename, the uploaded file will be stored at the given path
                                                  // using the filename indicated in the path.
                                                  path: "/public/oncorhynchus.jpg",
                                                  // Access permissions (either public or private)
                                                  access: .public)

// Call the function in your `Client` instance that takes care of file uploading.
// Please notice that some of the parameters are optional and have default values.
let multiPartUpload = client.multiPartUpload(// Set the URL pointing to the local file you want to upload.
                                             from: localURL,
                                             // Set the destination storage location here.
                                             // If none given, S3 location with default options is assumed.
                                             storeOptions: storeOptions,
                                             // Set to `false` if you don't want to use
                                             // Intelligent Ingestion regardless of whether it is available
                                             // for you.
                                             useIntelligentIngestionIfAvailable: true,
                                             // Set the dispatch queue where you want your upload progress
                                             // and completion handlers to be called.
                                             // Remember that any UI updates should be performed on the
                                             // main queue.
                                             // You can omit this parameter, and the main queue will be
                                             // used by default.
                                             queue: .main,
                                             // Set your upload progress handler here (optional)
                                             uploadProgress: uploadProgress) { response in
    // Try to obtain Filestack handle
    if let json = response?.json, let handle = json["handle"] as? String {
        // Use Filestack handle
    } else if let error = response?.error {
        // Handle error
    }
}

// Cancelling ongoing multipart upload.
multipartUpload.cancel()
```

Source: **https://github.com/filestack/filestack-swift**

Comment: Hi, I want to get the URL for the image or video I uploaded to blob. Couldn't find any function that bring back the URL any help??

Comment: Hi Adam, How can I setup Client to start upload using SAS (Shared Access Signature) ? And second question what is apiKey: "YOUR-API-KEY" in your snippet(Could you show some apiKey how it looks like?